# Under what conditions is a ratio between polynomial functions constant?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, fractions

I am studying ruled surfaces in $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ and I am trying to compare the Gaussian curvature of two such surfaces constructed along the same curve. In order to do so, I end up considering an expression of the form
$$
H(t,u)=\frac{f(t,u)}{g(t,u)},
$$
where both $f(t,u)$ and $g(t,u)$ are nonzero *polynomials of equal degree in* $u$.

I would like to know whether there is a simple way to examine the dependence of $H$ on $u$. In other words, under what conditions on numerator and denominator is the ratio independent of $u$?

Taking the derivative is not an option because the expression becomes really messy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear to me what sort of answer is useful to you. If you have explicit real polynomials $f(t, u), g(t, u)$ whose ratio is independent of $u$, then you could factor them over $\mathbb{R}[t, u]$ (or a computable subfield...), and all the irreducible factors that actually involve $u$ must cancel.

Why? In this case we have $f(t,u)/g(t,u) = f(t,0)/g(t,0)$, so $f(t,u) g(t,0) = g(t,u) f(t,0)$. As stated this is an equality on the level of functions, but since $\mathbb{R}$ is infinite, it's also an equality on the level of formal polynomials. Now take an irreducible factor $p(t, u)$ of $f(t, u)$ that actually depends on $u$. By unique factorization, $p(t, u)$ divides either $g(t, u)$ or $f(t, 0)$. Since it can't divide $f(t, 0)$, it must divide $g(t, u)$.

Another way to say it is that there are polynomials $\alpha(t), \beta(t), h(t, u)$ such that $f(t, u) = \alpha(t) h(t, u)$ and $g(t, u) = \beta(t) h(t, u)$. Note that the obvious constraint that the $u$-degree of $f$ and $g$ is equal is clear here.